# How to Wirelessly copy files in a folder in batches (simultaneously 2 or more files are being copied)?

Tags: wireless-networking, file-transfer

I didn't meant to say to use a batch file like I saw on a search on Google. What I mean is to copy a file in a folder while the other files are copying that are also in the folder... Because I'm trying to copy the whole 18GB folder to my Android phone, when it copies small files, the copy process gets slow too like 16 Kilobyte per second. But when the process is now copying like Win10.iso the speed goes to 2.75 Megabyte per second (not megabit or kilobit). I know I use spinning disk but I do believe that the head won't keep going back and forth and it won't slow down if you copy a folder with over 1K folders and 633 files because it is all in one containing folder. I made a .rar to this folder but it's like bigger than the original folder but when I tried to copy it to my phone, it was better and stable speeds. One thing I thought is that I can also go through several copy dialogs to perform simultaneous file copies...

Comment: What do you mean wirelessly? How does it relate to this? Did you try to extract the rar on your phone? Why would you copy so many files/folders to the phone? Did you try to copy multiple files to the device and did it decrease the needed time? What OS are you using? What Android is that phone running/which phone is it?

Comment: I am using built-in ftp on my my then I would enter the link in the explorer then i can now access my files, and copy and things like that

Comment: Your built-in ftp on what? Your phone? Android doesn't come with a default FTP from what I know.

Comment: My Android phone is Oppo and the file manager got it's own ftp